# The most efficient DHT

Tags: protocols, p2p, dht

What is the most **efficient** DHT? I am looking for name and/or some kind of implementation or related work, but I am not looking for the one that is most used.

Efficient in terms of CPU execution cycles, load balance, and memory consumption.

Comment: Efficient how? CPU cycles, network traffic, storage space?

Comment: reword your question to be more specific about your use case, and how it specifically defines "efficient", or the question is likely to get closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[These slides [PDF]](http://www.blackhole.sk/~v92/dfs/Bella_Pistagna_Riccobene_vodca04.pdf) describe a DHT that uses IDA (Information Dispersal Algorithm) for:

> - High Availability
> - No waste of Resources
> - No waste of Bandwidth
> - Simple and lightness protocol
> - It can be a start point for further works

Also, the DHT design described **does not need a leaving protocol**.

Regards,
Andreas

Comment: @Vincent, It seems to have been taken offline. I still had it on my computer so here is a link to the file in my public Dropbox: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11733855/Bella_Pistagna_Riccobene_vodca04.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Most DHTs are pretty similar in terms of functionality and differ mostly in how they handle neighbor sets and routing. It's not clear to me that one would be better than the other for any application. You would need to look at DHTs behavior and suitability and then choose the best based on your application.

A good technical comparison paper is [A performance vs. cost framework for evaluating DHT design tradeoffs under churn (PDF)](http://www.news.cs.nyu.edu/~jinyang/pub/infocom05-pvc.pdf). This paper compares several DHTs and discuss their suitability for different applications.